# tlmgr cannot access working repository

Tags: installing, texlive

I'm trying to install package from a repository via tlmgr and always get the error

```
tlmgr: package repository http://ctan.uni-altai.ru/
TLDownload::get_file: response error:
404 Not Found
permanent server connection set up, but downloading did not succeed!Retrying with wget.
```

Repository is working, I can access it via browser, I've also tried others. Sometimes errorcode is different e.g. 500.

```
$ latex -v
pdfTeX 3.1415926-2.3-1.40.12 (TeX Live 2011)
kpathsea version 6.0.1
Copyright 2011 Peter Breitenlohner (eTeX)/Han The Thanh (pdfTeX).
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the pdfTeX source.
Primary author of pdfTeX: Peter Breitenlohner (eTeX)/Han The Thanh (pdfTeX).
Compiled with libpng 1.5.2; using libpng 1.5.2
Compiled with zlib 1.2.5; using zlib 1.2.5
Compiled with xpdf version 3.02pl5
```

Any ideas?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) The actual TeXLive version is 2012, you are using 2011.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues here: One is that you are not specifying the right path, only the CTAN mirror. You have to use `http://ctan.uni-altai.ru/systems/texlive/tlnet/` instead.

The second issue is that you are using 2011, so even the above will not work anymore. You should install TeX Live 2012.